# sudo apt-get update focal and ppa error

Tags: apt, ppa

When I do sudo apt-get update I see an output like this:

```
Hit:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease
Ign:2 http://ppa.launchpad.net/gnome-terminator/ppa/ubuntu focal InRelease     
Err:3 http://ppa.launchpad.net/gnome-terminator/ppa/ubuntu focal Release       
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.85 80]
Hit:4 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu focal InRelease                 
Err:5 http://tr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease                
  Temporary failure resolving 'tr.archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:6 http://tr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'tr.archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:7 http://tr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'tr.archive.ubuntu.com'
Reading package lists... Done           
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/gnome-terminator/ppa/ubuntu focal Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

What should I do?

Comment: I quickly looked up one of the PPAs (personal package archive) you'd added, it's support ended with 16.04/2016-April release; your release is 20.04/focal which it doesn't support, so why did you add it?  PPAs are 3rd party sources, so all security checks are your responsibility.   (273 weeks ago was the last attention paid to it https://launchpad.net/~gnome-terminator/+archive/ubuntu/ppa  you need to improve your security checking)

Comment: I am very new to ubuntu and very confused about what means what I didn't add this package on purpose. I just tried to download it from ubuntu software and it gave an error and I gave up from installing it but now I can't even use sudo apt-get update onnormal ubuntu terminal I will try to remove that PPA

Comment: Why did you try to add the PPA? Do you want to install some software? We can try to help you if you ask a question about which software you are trying to install.

Answer (score 0):

At first you have to fix the network or mirror connectivity problems. You can change the actual mirror in the Software & Updates (`software-properties-gtk`) application

Then remove [problematic PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Egnome-terminator/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) which does not provide packages for your Ubuntu release, update package lists and install [Terminator from official *universe* repository](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/terminator):

```
sudo apt-add-repository -r ppa:gnome-terminator/ppa
sudo apt-add-repository universe
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install terminator
```